# Equation of tangent and normal for translated conics

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have a translated parabola
$(y-k)^2=4a(x-h)$ 
and I need to find the equation of its tangent, can I just replace $x$ and $y$ in 
$y=mx+a/m$ 
by $(x-h)$ and $(y-k)$? 
similarly can I do that with its equation of normal?
And if not, what will be the correct equations of normal and tangent?

P.S. I would appreciate it if you explained it using the theory of conics rather than calculus as I haven’t studied calculus yet.

Comment: No, $(h, k)$ represents the vertex of the parabola. If your tangent line doesn't pass through $(h, k)$ it doesn't make sense in point-slope form

Comment: but I am shifting the origin by (h,k) so shouldn’t it be correct if I used this method?

Comment: But the vertex of the parabola isn't always going to be a point on the tangent line...

Comment: yes it isn’t. And if I put (h,k) in (y-k)=m(x-h) +a/m it won’t satisfy it either

Answer (score -1):

What basically happens during translation is the shift of the origin.(0,0) shifts to (h,k).Thus, every y coordinate changes to y-k and x to x-h.Think like this-
"You have a circular rubber-band, and on it you have a net.When you 'move' the 'net' keeping the circle's position under it fixed, you actually shift the origin in terms of coordinate geometry.With reference to the previous position of the net, you have shifted it to a new position, by a distance 'h' horizontally and 'k' vertically.Thus the new origin with respect to the old has 'shifted' to (h,k).And so changes the x and y coordinates, which, too, 'shifts' by h and k...

Comment: So you’re saying that I can replace x and y by (x-h) and (y-k)? It will give me the correct equations?

Comment: yes of course :-)

Comment: How does this answer the question, the OP seems the understand transformations of conics. Also, please use MathJax.

Comment: I just tried to explain it in my own words